Patienter ou attendre
Bonjour,
Je voudrais savoir s'il est correct de dire:

Je préfère le patienter

ou

je préfère l’attendre.

Avec des règles citées s’il vous plaît.
Merci.

On ne peut pas patienter quelque chose/quelqu'un, ce verbe étant intransitif. On dira donc :

je préfère l'attendre.

Sans complément, les deux se disent, patienter étant plus soutenu.

Je préfère attendre.


Je préfère patienter.

